# Why ISO Format Date & Time gets Converted into the Array of Numbers while doing API calls

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, api, localdatetime

I am using LocalDateTime in spring boot application and i am storing date and time in ISO format in mongodb and it is also getting stored there but when I am making API calls to the end points of my application it is showing list of numbers instead of showing the date in ISO format you can also see

[image]

[image]

Here is the class
[image]

I am not getting why it is working like this way.

Comment: Where are you using the `LocalDateTime`? Can you show the conversion or at least where in your code you are using that class? A little remark: For an ISO formatted `String` including the `Z` at the end (*Zulu* or just UTC) you'd be better off using an `OffsetDateTime`, I think, maybe even a `ZonedDateTime`.

Comment: Yes I have added the screenshot of that now. @deHaar

Comment: You are probably using Jackson for the conversion to JSON and Jackson unfortunately does the wrong thing by default. You have to configure it yourself to use ISO-8601 format. See this article: [Formatting JSON Dates in Spring Boot](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-formatting-json-dates)